# How to get correct click scaling from custom GROB layout in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a situation in which I would like to have multiple ggplot graphics in a Shiny app.  Typically this is addressed via the facet techniques.  However, in my case some of my x values are categorical and others are continuous.  To try to address this issue, I have use the `gridExtra` package to combine the multiple plots into a single plot using the `arrangeGrob` and `grid.arrange` function.  When I use the click action on the plot, the returned coordinates do not correspond to the points in the plot.  The following is a self-contained example:

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

test_addin <- function() {

  ui <- miniPage(
    miniTitleBar(title = 'Example', right = miniTitleBarButton("done", "Done", primary = TRUE)),
    miniContentPanel(plotOutput('plot', height = '100%', click = 'plot_click'))
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
      tmp = isolate(input$plot_click)
      cat(sprintf('Location was: %0.2f, %0.2f\n', tmp$x, tmp$y))
    })

    plot_reactive = reactive({
      contdata = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10), term = as.factor('one'))
      discdata = data.frame(x = as.factor(rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 5)), y = runif(10), term = as.factor('two'))

      contplot = ggplot(contdata) + theme_bw() +
        geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        labs(x = '', y = '')

      discplot = ggplot(discdata) + theme_bw() +
        geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        labs(x = '', y = '')

      p1 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(contplot))
      p2 = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(discplot))

      grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1, p2, layout_matrix = matrix(c(1, 2), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)))
    })

    observe({
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
          plot_reactive()
      })
    })

    observeEvent(input$done, {
      stopApp()
    })
  }

  viewer <- paneViewer(300)
  runGadget(ui, server, viewer = viewer)
}

test_addin()
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction to make this function as intended?  I have spent far too long on this (read as browsing ggplot and shiny source code) to not ask the question.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I wanted to add that when I was trying to get this to work, I had also tried to trick the facet into allowing this through some tricky mapping.  Unfortunately, this failed to produce the results I was looking for.  I know that shiny can pull the information from a facet, I am just not sure how to add that information into my custom grob layout such that shiny can do the transformation.

I could also just try to use base graphics.  That might be the most correct thing to do.  I do however, like the ggplot system.

Comment: Why not display it in two content panels side-by-side? Then you avoid the `grid.arrange` step that is screwing up your mapping.

Comment: I did the two panels to exhibit the issue.  In the full code, there will be N panels and I don't know ahead of time how many will be continuous and how many will be categorical.

Comment: You might try looking at the `cowplot` package, maybe ask questions on github if this case can be handled there. Anything I can think of feels like an awful lot of work.